# Reverse proxy using url token

Tags: proxy, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have a working [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) installation that lives at `https://example.com`, it has a hand full of triggers that can be passed in the URL.

`https://example.com/this` acts as a redirect, but if you prefix `this` with `+` so that we get `https://example.com/+this` we get some custom function. Likewise, if we add the `+` to the end of the URL like so `https://example.com/this+` we can display some stats, etc.

How would I proxy these functions through sub-domains so that when `https://a.example.com/this` is requested the user is presented with the same data as from `https://example.com/+this` but at the new url, and when `https://b.example.com/this` is requested, the user sees the same result as from `https://example.com/this+`?

`this` uses a character set of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

I can't seem to get anywhere with this. I know that `mod_rewrite` can help here, that `mod_proxy` is going to be needed and can match regex, and that `SSLPRoxyEngine on` needs to be set, what's the best approach?

Comment: What is the format of the URL(s) you want to send these requests to? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm hoping to make http://a.example.com/this be the point of access instead of http://example.com/+this... Likewise, http://b.example.com/this for http://example.com/this+ 

I would need to remove '+' and preserve 'this'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using mod_rewrite / mod_proxy:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Request https://example.com/+this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?\+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ https://a.%1/$1 [P]

# Request https://example.com/this+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\+$ https://b.%1/$1 [P]
```

This assumes `this` consists of just the characters `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` (updated with respect to comments). Alternatively, you can use the `NC` (`NOCASE` - case insensitive) flag on the `RewriteRule` and specify a *pattern* of just `[a-z0-9]`. Or, if you are prepared to allow an underscore as well, then you can use the `\w` shorthand character class (same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` - "word" characters). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)\+$ https://b.%1/$1 [P]
```

**UPDATE:** After rereading your *updated* question I think I had the logic reversed! (Although the first one worked?) Try the following instead:

```
# https://a.example.com/this TO https://example.com/+this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ https://%1/+$1 [P]

# https://b.example.com/this TO https://example.com/this+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^b\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ https://%1/$1+ [P]
```

If these directives are in `.htaccess` then the `RewriteRule` *pattern* can be simplified a bit... the `/?` prefix can be omitted. So, `^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` becomes `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$`.

Note that these directives will need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, before your "front controller", otherwise they will not get processed.

And when proxying to HTTPS (SSL protocol) you will need to make sure that `SSLProxyEngine On` is set in your server config.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. Also, `this` can consist of both upper and lower case letters, and 0-9.

Comment: This seems to work well for the custom function at `https://example.com/+this` but it isn't working for YOURLS built in stats function at `https://example.com/this+`. I'm assuming it has something to do with YOURLS, and not your regex wizardry. 

I updated the question to reflect the base62 encode range.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the appropriate regex (yes, you can change the character class to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - note that you had a "typo" in your comment, make sure that's not been copied into your actual code). The regex seems OK on the `this+` rule, so there may be "something else" affecting this, particularly if the first rule works OK. Do you have any other mod_rewrite directives in your config file? Presumably it works OK if you request `https://b.example.com/this` directly?

Comment: When you say it "isn't working for YOURLS built in stats function", what actually happens? Any errors?

Comment: All original urls still work, and `a.example.com/this` works as a replacement for 'example.com/+this'. When I try using `b.example.com/this` for either `example.com/this+` or `example.com/@this`, both of which do not bypass the normal YOURLS function sets (ie., they both have anything at all to do with actual, short URL's), then I get returned to `example.com`, which is the default behavior for a failed keyword match as I have things configured. There is no error that is expressed, so it appears as if YOURLS is handing this as if I have asked for a non-existent short url.

Comment: nice trick with the `\w`, but YOURLS restricts itself to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` so I think just keeping it tightly bound is the way to go.

Comment: Ah, (after rereading your updated question) I think I've got your logic the wrong way round...?! You want to be able to request a URL of the form `https://a.example.com/this` but be proxied to the "real URL" which is `example.com/this+`?

Comment: Yes. But I want it to be transparent. So the url remains `a.example.com/this`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just to confirm, both the subdomains resolve to the same place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49667/discussion-between-joshp-23-and-w3dk).